# Encoding meta information in Hive

Tags: hive, character-encoding

Ask for advice

```
hive> select version();
OK
2.3.3 r95e2ca94dcfdc6c2f5435a3de4094e1ab0f39976
```

The field comments table displays question marks instead of Cyrillic ( which is where I write comments). 
If comments are written in Latin letters, then everything is fine. 
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_com`(
  `id` string COMMENT 'Test comment',
  `di` string COMMENT Тест коммент'
  ) STORED AS ORC
  TBLPROPERTIES ( 'store.charset'='UTF-8', 'retrieve.charset'='UTF-8');
```

=====>>>>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzK4t.png)

```
`id` string COMMENT 'Test comment', 
`di` string COMMENT '???? ???????'
```

I tried different table formats and different ways to create it , but nothing helps.

Data in the table Cyrillic is displayed normally.

I tried changing comments via

```
ALTER TABLE test_com CHANGE id id STRING COMMENT 'Number of the house (hold)';
```

But it doesn 't help

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What database is backing your Hive Metastore, and what is its character set? In MySQL for example Hive explicitly sets COMMENT field charset as `latin-1` (see https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/rel/release-2.3.3/metastore/scripts/upgrade/mysql/hive-schema-2.3.0.mysql.sql#L54) which would be a problem for Cyrillic.

Comment: Postgresql supports our metastore Hive

Comment: Then next question -- what is the char encoding for Hive metastore database in Postgres? `$ psql -l`

Comment: @mazaneicha

  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 ambari    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | ambari=CTc/postgres

Comment: Frankly I don't see HMS database among them, but maybe you called it `postgres` or `ambari` ?!? If yes, do comments appear correctly when you just query `COLUMNS_V2` table via `psql`?

Comment: Hi

@mazaneicha, I returned to this question. I dug into the settings and really by default metastore in the mysql database. There is a hive database there. It contains the specified table

I changed the encoding for this field to utf8, but it didn 't help, signs anyway "????"

Comment: So... taking Hive out of the picture, if you now SQL UPDATE the table with Cyrillic comments can you read them back?

Comment: I tried updating this comment directly in metastore and then it displays normally. But as soon as I update this comment via beeline, I get the "ALTER TABLE" again ????

Comment: Hmmm... how do you execute `ALTER TABLE`? Are you using Linux/beeline? If yes, maybe you can try changing session encoding -- `export LANG=ru_RU.utf8` and `export LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8` -- and only then run beeline.

Comment: Thank you for your responsiveness. I apologize for not promptly answering questions. I install the locale as you wrote and then run beeline. Then run the update comment - beeline

: jdbc:hive2://192.168.72.200:10000> ALTER TABLE avs_ors.test_com CHANGE id id STRING COMMENT 'Тестирую комментарий';

It doesn 't help, do the signs remain "???? " And found an open task on this topic https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18083

Maybe I should try to re- create this table, but in utf8 ...

Comment: Thanks for digging up that JIRA. You can certainly try to recreate the table to see if it helps, especially after changing that nasty `...DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;` :) But I see another issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13983 unresolved, which looks exactly like what you experience. Updating MySQL directly might be the only option :(( or changing the backed DB to Postgres!