# Special characters in Dataproc partition columns

Tags: apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-metastore

I'm using Spark `3.1.2` on Goole Dataproc image version `2.0.15-debian10` with Dataproc managed metastore version `3.1.2`. The following snippet works fine with a GCS backed table `mydb.mytable`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark.createDataFrame([Row(x='a', y=1)]).write.saveAsTable('mydb.mytable',
                       mode='overwrite',
                       partitionBy=['x'])
```

However, when adding a special character to partition column:

```
spark.createDataFrame([Row(x='ก', y=1)]).write.saveAsTable('mydb.mytable',
                       mode='overwrite',
                       partitionBy=['x'])
```

the operation fails with the following exception:

```
21/08/03 10:44:27 ERROR hive.ql.metadata.Hive: MetaException(message:Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT DISTINCT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MPartition' AS `NUCLEUS_TYPE`,`A0`.`CREATE_TIME`,`A0`.`LAST_ACCESS_TIME`,`A0`.`PART_NAME`,`A0`.`PART_ID` FROM `PARTITIONS` `A0` LEFT OUTER JOIN `TBLS` `B0` ON `A0`.`TBL_ID` = `B0`.`TBL_ID` LEFT OUTER JOIN `DBS` `C0` ON `B0`.`DB_ID` = `C0`.`DB_ID` WHERE `B0`.`TBL_NAME` = ? AND `C0`.`NAME` = ? AND `A0`.`PART_NAME` = ? AND `C0`.`CTLG_NAME` = ?)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$add_partitions_req_result$add_partitions_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$add_partitions_req_result$add_partitions_req_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$add_partitions_req_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_add_partitions_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.add_partitions_req(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1898)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.add_partitions(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:627)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.add_partitions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2336)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.add_partitions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createPartitions(Hive.java:2097)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_13.createPartitions(HiveShim.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$createPartitions$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:609)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.createPartitions(HiveClientImpl.scala:602)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$createPartitions$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:1007)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createPartitions(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.createPartitions(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createPartitions(SessionCatalog.scala:1050)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AlterTableRecoverPartitionsCommand.$anonfun$addPartitions$1(ddl.scala:792)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AlterTableRecoverPartitionsCommand.$anonfun$addPartitions$1$adapted(ddl.scala:774)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AlterTableRecoverPartitionsCommand.addPartitions(ddl.scala:774)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AlterTableRecoverPartitionsCommand.run(ddl.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:753)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:626)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The data gets written correctly to GCS but updating the metastore fails. My guess is this is caused by using `latin1` encoding in the managed metastore. Also, using `spark.write.parquet(...)` works (as the metastore is not used).

Is it possible to configure Dataproc to properly handle any UTF-8 values in partition columns? I would like to avoid using any encoding (like URL encoding) in the application logic.

Comment: Can you try updating the encoding of the table with `ALTER TABLE mytable SET serdeproperties ('serialization.encoding'='UTF-8');`

Comment: Thanks @Dagang, tried but no luck.

Comment: There are other 2 related properties `TBLPROPERTIES ( 'store.charset'='UTF-8', 'retrieve.charset'='UTF-8')`, not sure if they help or not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658595/encoding-meta-information-in-hive

Comment: Tried those as well, still no luck

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Hive Metastore's MySQL schema does not support that character:

`PART_NAME` varchar(767) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/metastore/scripts/upgrade/mysql/hive-schema-2.3.0.mysql.sql#L211

You could reach out to the Hive community to check whether a larger character set is OK: https://github.com/apache/hive#useful-mailing-lists